# Why signals occupy small portion after being scaled and how to change it?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-analyzer

I am a newbie and try to understand why signals watched on logic analyzer shrink on screen when resolution is changed (as on the pics) so that they occupy a small region on the screen? It'a a continuous signal actually. Is it possible to see the signals on the full screen and how it can be achieved? I don't mind them to look smaller (it's alright) but want them to be seen on full screen, not just a small portion of the screen near its centre where they are overcrowded and not really seen anymore.

I use DigiView Dv-100 logic analyzer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When the time scale is changed from 5ms/Div to 20ms/Div to 100ms/Div, each division represents a larger period of time, so that's why the signal is displayed on a smaller region of the screen. Effectively going from 5ms/Div to 100ms/Div is a "zoom out". I think you want to "zoom in", so turn the control the opposite direction to change to less time per division, right?

Comment: The signals zoomed out is okay, it's not a problem. The problem is that the region of visibility of the signals gets zoomed out on screen too. So, let's the signals be smaller but still occupy whole screen as it was with smaller resolution.

Comment: did you actually measure then entire period you are trying to visualize?

Comment: The logic analyzer is continuously run. So, yes, I suppose.

Comment: It seems I have made a progress with it. There are two modes - continuous (its result is shown on the pictures above) and Run[Arm trigger]. With the latter, after 'Stop(Retrieve data)', it occupies whole screen as I wanted in my original question. I still have not got exactly how it works (and it's not well explained in the logic analyzer' manual) but, at least, I have an answer now.